# Bash error after opening Terminal and running shell scripts (CentOS)

Tags: bash, centos6

Every time I open Terminal in CentOS 6.4, I get the error:

```
bash: usr/local/bin: No such file or directory
```

I've checked .bashrc and .bash_profile to see if there are any lines that reference usr/local/bin, but haven't found anything. The same error also appears when I switch to root, or run a shell script.

Is it as simple as adding a backslash in front of usr? Like so--

```
/usr/local/bin
```

Still don't know where the error is happening though. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try running `bash -x` and watch the output for mention of `usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Maybe `usr/local/bin` is in your PATH? Items are separated by `:`, run `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Maybe there is a script in /etc/profile.d which is wrongly trying to refer to usr/local/bin ?

Comment: Have you looked in your `.profile`, `.bash_profile` and related files in your home directory?  Have you looked in `/etc` at similar files?

Answer (score 1):

This is strange as the normal bash directory on a centos 6.4 system is /bin/bash, however I would advise you to check the following:

```
echo $SHELL
```

It should pull your SHELL environment variable to show you where what shell you are using, normally it looks like this:

SHELL=/bin/bash

If it's different say for example:

SHELL=usr/local/bin/bash

then I would check your passwd file to make sure your users default shell is pointing to the right place.

username:x:601:601::/home/username:**/bin/bash**

Also I would suggest check where you shell actually lives

```
which bash
/bin/bash
```

And make sure everything is pointing to the correct location.