# After uninstalling mysqlm, the command is still working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to reinstall MySQL on my centos os. So I removed every single file and packages that is associated with MySQL. But after all that, when I type in mysql in the command line, instead of saying it's unknown, it says
    -bash: /usr/bin/mysq; No such file or directory.
Is that normal? Or did I do something wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this show: rpm -qa | grep -i ^mysql

Comment: it says grep: -: No such file or directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434728/bash-error-after-opening-terminal-and-running-shell-scripts-centos

Comment: When I do echo $SHELL and which bash it says /bin/bash which according to the link is normal.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, it worked fine after a reboot. I guess I should always reboot the machine before posting anything and see if that fixes it :)